# AWeberApi - could not get Subscribers email

Tags: api, aweber

I run this code

print_r($list->subscribers);

You can see at the result I pasted below that there is no subscriber name and email... I tried all the sample codes i could find in the web and all of them have the same result.

Now my question is, how to get the emails of all the subscribers aside from the code I used above?

```
            [last_followup_sent_link] => https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/6023076/lists/20746327/campaigns/f105556951
            [city] => 
            [http_etag] => "d6a652460dae642a0732ecf75003de4t05be96f66a1-7c14178a7fa0b2a2b7fb74be93ff058ac477ea43"
            [ad_tracking] => my_web_form
            [dma_code] => 
            [last_followup_message_number_sent] => 1
            [last_followup_sent_at] => 2011-11-17 04:52:19-05:00
            [latitude] => 
            [is_verified] => 1
            [status] => subscribed
            [area_code] => 
            [unsubscribed_at] => 
            [self_link] => 
            [unsubscribe_method] => 
            [resource_type_link] => https://api.aweber.com/1.0/#subscriber
            [subscription_method] => signup form
            [subscribed_at] => 2011-11-17 04:51:41-05:00
            [region] => 
            [longitude] => 
            [verified_at] => 2011-11-17 04:52:19-05:00
            [country] =>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you did not grant access to subscriber info in your app. Choose Edit -> Permission Settings, put a check mark in the Request Subscriber Info box then choose save permission settings and then choose save. If done correctly, you should be back at the apps page and it will now be displaying the additional permissions.

You will have to reset the key/secret and then get a new Oauth token and secret as well. When that takes place and it asks for permission, you should see a box above the login credentials detailing the request for personal subscriber details. If you don't see it, something is wrong.

Once completed you should see all subscriber data including email address.